# A secure commenting system for php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to implement a commenting system for my website. I looked around and found CKEditor to be the best WYSIWYG editor I found. I tried its bbcode output and it works perfectly. However if I use bbcode output, when I want to show the comments to the users, I should use a reliable parser to parse the bbcode to HTML. If I use HTML output, I may need to use something to prevent XSS in the comments. Which way you suggest for a simple commenting system. I already integrated CKEditor to my system and prefer a very lightweight and simple approach without so much bloat (like PEAR). Also, StackOverflow seems pretty awesome. Is it possible to use something similar for my php?

Comment: Have you considered integrating Disqus or another 3rd party? Their core competency is commenting, and are much further ahead on these issues(spam, XSS, griefing, etc)

Comment: I would like to know the reason for the downvote...

Comment: Yes, [Disqus is free](http://disqus.com/addons/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I should use a reliable parser to parse the bbcode to HTML.

PHP has a [pecl BBCode extension.](http://pecl.php.net/package/bbcode)

> Also, StackOverflow seems pretty awesome. Is it possible to use something similar for my php?

SO uses Markdown. [Markdown parser in PHP](http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/) is also available

Comment: Is the PECL extension reliable? How can I install it? Thanks.

Comment: @AlirezaNoori install it by `pecl install bbcode` or `pear install bbcode`

Comment: Thank you. But I tried both your command and: `pecl install -f pecl/bbcode`. None worked. Upon build it says: `ERROR: The DSP bbcode.dsp does not exist.`

Comment: I'm using php version 5.3.8 and tried to `php_bbcode.dll` from [this link](http://downloads.php.net/pierre/) but it says that it's compiled on a different version.

Comment: If its windows compiling would be near impossible. Try [HTML_BBCodeParser](http://pear.php.net/package/HTML_BBCodeParser) package instead.

Comment: If you dont have pear on windows, follow [these instructions](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.getting.php#installation.getting.windows) from pear.php.net